# Transferring parameters on 64 bit Linux in registers

Tags: linux, performance, optimization, x86-64, cpu-registers

I understand 64 bit Linux allows one to pass the first six integer function parameters and first eight floating point function parameters via registers.

If I had seven integer parameters to pass, is there any way for me to use one of the un-used float registers for the seventh integer, without sacrificing performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are writing your own assembly code, you can utilize the registers in whatever way you want (ok, maybe not quite that liberal, but you can be free to ignore the ABI, sorta). However, if you are interfacing with library code (or system calls, or parts of your program compiled from a higher level language, or ...) that was written to follow the standard ABI, you will have to follow the same restrictions in the portions of your code that form/use the ABI-compliant interfaces.

Comment: Ok so you are saying if the function was written in inline assembly, the rule of which parameters being passed via registers etc goes out of the window?

Comment: No. Inline assembly (in C or C++, I'm presuming) will have to be subject to the constraints the compiler places on it to make it interface properly with the rest of the code. However, you could have your inline assembly call a function that you've written purely in assembly, that can call other pure assembler functions, etc.... As long as you properly save/restore registers before getting back to the high-level code, you can use registers a lot more freely.